# Use of the verb "Too see"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the text below on a webpage:

*Presenting to you, the Hyundai torque monsters.

See how even the clouds and the sun have gone into hiding*

After doing a search I found the following text:

*See how even the smallest flame can illuminate the shadows.

Never underestimate the brilliance or necessity of the light you bring into the world. Happy Hanukkah, everyone.*

I was intrigued by the use of the verb "to see" in these cases. The correct thing here would not be to use the verb "to look" or perhaps the verb "to notice". Can the verb "to see" be used with that kind of meaning?

Comment: Yes, "see" can be used as an imperative, as in "Three blind mice / See how they run!".

Comment: @Itamar There's a typo in the title of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"See" is being used as an imperative, a command. The reader is instructed to observe something.

If you want to command someone to, for example, run, you can say, "Run away!" If you want to command someone to see something, you can say, "See this!"

There's nothing particularly unusual about the usage here. I suppose "see" is rarely used as an imperative, but there's no reason why it can't be -- like almost any other verb.

Sure, you could use other words. You could say "Notice" or "Take cognizance of the fact that". But "see" is fine in context.

Is there some reason why you think it is not appropriate?

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for clarifying this for me. Honestly, I don't know how to explain very well why the use of the verb "to hear" didn't seem very appropriate for me in this type of sentence. I vaguely remember an English teacher at my secondary school many years ago (decades ago, actually) mentioning something about this, but I'm not quite sure what he said. I was simply in doubt and decided to seek help to make sure it could be used. Thanks again.

Comment: Using "see" seems a bit poetic or old fashioned to me, although evidently still in use. I think "look at how..." or "watch how..." are other common ways of expressing it.

Comment: Thanks for adding this info, Stuart. It made the understanding even clearer for me.